# Linear Algebra, p-norm

Tags: linear-algebra

If $D$ is a diagonal matrix such that $D=diag(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,...\lambda_n) \in \mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ and $||.||_{(p)}$ the norm induced by the $||.||_p$. Show that $||D||_{(p)}=max(|\lambda_i|,\space i=1,....,n)$.

I know by definition that $||Ax||_{(p)}=max(||Ax||_p, ||x||_p=1)$. But I don't know how to make this proof.

$$||Ax||_p=(\sum_{i=1}^n|a_i|^p)^\frac{1}{p}$$

Comment: I am failing to follow your definition of p-norm.

Comment: Already added @PredragPunosevac

Comment: I think you mean to say $||A||_{(p)}=\max\{ ||Ax||_p:||x||_p=1\}$, right? And you are trying to find $||D||_{(p)}$, not $||D||_p$, right?

Comment: Yeah man, I typed wrong @Shalop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote $e_i$ as the $i^{th}$ standard basis vector. Choose $k$ such that $|\lambda_k|=\max_{1 \leq i\leq n} |\lambda_i|$. Then $||e_k||_p=1$, and $||De_k||_p= || \lambda_ke_k||_p = |\lambda_k| = \max |\lambda_i|$.Thus $$||D||_{(p)}=\max\{ ||Dx||_p : ||x||=1\} \geq ||De_k||_p = \max |\lambda_i|$$

On the other hand if $||x||_p=1$, then

$||Dx||_p$

$=||(\lambda_1x_1,...,\lambda_nx_n) ||_p $

$= \bigg(\sum_1^n |\lambda_jx_j|^p\bigg)^{\frac{1}{p}} $

$\leq \bigg( \max|\lambda_i|^p \sum_1^n |x_j|^p \bigg)^{\frac{1}{p}} $

$= \max |\lambda_i| \bigg(\sum_1^n |x_j|^p \bigg)^{\frac{1}{p}} $

$= \max|\lambda_i| \cdot||x||_p$

$=\max |\lambda_i|$

Therefore $||D||_{(p)} \leq \max |\lambda_i|$

We showed that $||D||_{(p)} \leq \max |\lambda_i|$ and $||D||_{(p)} \geq \max |\lambda_i|$, so it follows that $||D||_{(p)} = \max |\lambda_i|$.

Comment: Why $||De_k||_p=||\lambda_ke_k||_p$

Comment: Because $D$ is a diagonal matrix and $\lambda_k$ is the $k^{th}$ entry on the diagonal, so $De_k=\lambda_ke_k$.